# password recovery key is invalid on custom reset

Tags: password, reset

I am trying to use a custom password recovery form instead of the default WP. The url link for resetting the password is returning 'invalid key' error. Does anyone have any help with where the problem is?

```
<?php
global $wpdb, $user_ID;

function validate_url() {
    global $post;
    $page_url = esc_url(get_permalink( $post->ID ));
    $urlget = strpos($page_url, "?");
if ($urlget === false) {
    $concate = "?";
} else {
    $concate = "&";
}
return $page_url.$concate;
}

if (!$user_ID) { //block logged in users

if(isset($_GET['key']) && $_GET['action'] == "reset_pwd") {
    $reset_key = $_GET['key'];
    $user_login = $_GET['login'];
    $user_data = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare("SELECT ID, user_login, user_email FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_activation_key = %s AND user_login = %s", $reset_key, $user_login));

$user_login = $user_data->user_login;
$user_email = $user_data->user_email;

if(!empty($reset_key) && !empty($user_data)) {
    $new_password = wp_generate_password(7, false);
    //echo $new_password; exit();
    wp_set_password( $new_password, $user_data->ID );
    //mailing reset details to the user
    $message = __('Your new password for the account at:') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= get_option('siteurl') . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= sprintf(__('Password: %s'), $new_password) . "\r\n\r\n";
    $message .= __('You can now login with your new password at: ') . get_option('siteurl')."/login" . "\r\n\r\n";

if ( $message && !wp_mail($user_email, 'Password Reset Request', $message) ) {
    echo "<div class='error'>Email failed to send for some unknown reason</div>";
exit();
}
else {
    $redirect_to = get_bloginfo('url')."/login?action=reset_success";
    wp_safe_redirect($redirect_to);
    exit();
}
} 
else echo "<div class='error'>Not a Valid Key</div>";
exit('Not a Valid Key.');

}
//exit();


if($_POST['action'] == "password_reset"){
if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['password_nonce'], "password_nonce")) {
    exit("No trick please");
}  
if(empty($_POST['user_input'])) {
    echo "<div class='error'>Please enter your Username or E-mail address</div>";
exit();
}
//We shall SQL escape the input
$user_input = $wpdb->escape(trim($_POST['user_input']));

if ( strpos($user_input, '@') ) {
    //$user_data = get_user_by_email($user_input);//deprecated
    $user_data = get_user_by('email', $user_input);
    if(empty($user_data) || $user_data->caps[administrator] == 1) { //delete the condition $user_data->caps[administrator]     == 1, if you want to allow password reset for admins also
    echo "<div class='error'>Invalid E-mail address!</div>";
    exit();
    }
}
else {
    //$user_data = get_userdatabylogin($user_input);//deprecated
    $user_data = get_user_by('login', $user_input);
    if(empty($user_data) || $user_data->caps[administrator] == 1) { //delete the condition $user_data->caps[administrator]     == 1, if you want to allow password reset for admins also
    echo "<div class='error'>Invalid Username!</div>";
    exit();
    }
}

$user_login = $user_data->user_login;
$user_email = $user_data->user_email;

$key = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT user_activation_key FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_login = %s", $user_login    ));
if(empty($key)) {
    //key(array)
    $key = wp_generate_password(20, false);
    $wpdb->update($wpdb->users, array('user_activation_key' => $key), array('user_login' => $user_login)); 
}

//mailing reset details to the user
$message = __('Someone requested that the password be reset for the following account:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= get_option('siteurl') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= sprintf(__('Username: %s'), $user_login) . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('If this was a mistake, just ignore this email and nothing will happen.') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= __('To reset your password, visit the following address:') . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= validate_url() . "action=reset_pwd&key=$key&login=" . rawurlencode($user_login) . "\r\n";

if ( $message && !wp_mail($user_email, 'Password Reset Request', $message) ) {
    echo "<div class='error'>Email failed to send for some unknown reason.</div>";
exit();
}
else {
    echo "<div class='message'>We have just sent you an email with Password reset instructions.</div>";
exit();
}
} else { 
?>

<form class="user_form form" id="wp_pass_reset" action="" method="post">     
    <input type="text" class="text" name="user_input" value="" /><br />
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="password_reset" />
    <input type="hidden" name="password_nonce" value="<?php echo wp_create_nonce("password_nonce"); ?>" />
    <input type="submit" id="submitbtn" class="reset_password" name="submit" value="Reset Password" />          
</form>
```

Thanks to Kannan at http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Create-a-Wordpress-Custom-Password-Reset-Page-Template/76026 for this tutorial.